# SQL Server nested select query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table and I need to run a query using a column without index, and therefore it's taking a long time to run.

For example:

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM Table
WHERE NonIndexColumn > 10
```

To speed it up (without adding index) I'm runing the query on small amount of rows from the table, using a query with indexed column, and expect it to be very fast

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP (10) *
     FROM Table
     WHERE IndexColumn > 10)
WHERE NonIndexColumn > 10
```

but unfortunately it's still very slow, although the inner query is very fast, and the outer query is running only on 10 rows

Can some one explain how the nested select is working, and how do I need to write it to make it run fast

Thanks

Comment: Where's your `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Show the execution plan of second query. Also did you try creating index on `NonIndexColumn` ?

Comment: And if you're performing a query against a non-indexed columns, then the entire table is likely going to have to be scanned. The lack of indexing is likely the problem.

Comment: Is the ORDER BY is necessary?

Comment: For a `TOP`, yes. Otherwise you're just getting a random/arbitrary row; which means your results will be inconsistent each time you run the query. And if you're just using the query to check for existence, then use `EXISTS`

Comment: I cant create an index on the column because it will cost too much with the performance of the insertion

Comment: *"because it will cost too much with the performance of the insertion"* Why do you say that? Do you have lots of other indexes on the table already, or is your instance's host that underpowered?

Comment: a random reasult is good enough for me

Comment: There really isn't anyway around this performance issue. You want a record where that condition is true and in order for the database to find records where that condition is true, it will have to scan the table. Unless there is an index to scan instead.

Comment: *"a random reasult is good enough for me"* then what are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want any row that meet the condition

Comment: Then that second query very likely could easily give you a false negative. The first 10 rows that SQL Server "finds" may well not meet the condition of the outer query.

Comment: What @Larnu is telling you is exactly what your query is already telling you:  you may have entries where *IndexColumn* is greater than 10 (which may change on you, without an ORDER BY), then those entries may not return anything, assuming *NonIndexColumn* will not be above 10.  In other news, outside of indexing, not sure there's a way to really speed this up, with the exception of maybe ditching the subquery.

Comment: I'm truly sure that the inner condition will always contains rows meeting the outer condition

Comment: If your so sure, then what's wrong with `SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM Table WHERE IndexColumn > 10`? Surely that too will therefore meet the outer condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT TOP (10) *
FROM Table
INTO #Temp
WHERE IndexColumn > 10


CREATE INDEX IX_Temp_Col1
ON dbo.#Temp (NonIndexColumn)


SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE ...
```

Comment: The problem, here, however, is that this could easily mean that none of the rows inserted into `#Temp` will meet the criteria. This would mean that the OP ***thinks*** no rows in `[Table]` meet the criteria, however that is wrong; it's just that the 10 arbitrary rows returned in the first `SELECT` didn't meet the requirements of the `WHERE` in the second.

Comment: your solution is working, but it create a new table for each query. And I'm trying to understand how the nested query is working

Comment: @amichai its working because Mohammad inserts data into a temp table and then Creates an index on that temp table (for faster reads) . Finally, he is giving you a select FROM temp table not nested query how you originally wanted.

Comment: @junketsu exactly (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I think you should reconsider indexing (or maybe rethinking how to approach this), have you thought of simply shrinking your query into one query?  Also, restricting to 1 column may speed up your process, given that you're just looking for any result, not a specific result. (Untested; you may not be able to do order by in a cte; I don't recall, as I normally don't.)

```
SELECT TOP (1) IndexColumn 
FROM TABLE
WHERE NonIndexColumn > 10 AND IndexColumn > 10
ORDER BY IndexColumn
```

You might be able to do this too, if you *really* need to get top 10, then top 1.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT TOP (10) IndexColumn 
FROM TABLE
WHERE NonIndexColumn > 10 AND IndexColumn > 10
ORDER BY IndexColumn 
)
SELECT TOP 1 FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Some SQL paltforms will perform better with a CTE instead of a sub-query.

Like this:

```
WITH Just10 AS
(
  SELECT TOP (10) *
  FROM Table
  WHERE IndexColumn > 10
)
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM Just10
WHERE NonIndexColumn > 10
```

Since the compiler will put the results of the Just10 into memory.

Which can be seen in the execution plan.

> This is variation on creating a temp table with `INSERT into #temp` that can be more efficient if the compiler decides it can just put all the data in memory.

Comment: @amichai again, why?

Answer (score 0):

Using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is unorthodox.  You have no control over which matching row is returned.  And, if you run the query twice (or even twice as a subquery in the same query), you *could* get different results.

This query is simply doing a scan of the table and it should be stopping at the first row that matches the condition:

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM Table
WHERE NonIndexColumn > 10;
```

If this is taking a long time, then it is taking a long time to scan the table and find a matching record.  Or, some other process is locking the table.  (Or if your table is view, then all bets are off.)  I don't think using an index column is going to help, unless you know there is some relationship between the two columns.

You should be able to speed this up by creating an index on that column.